# Is there any way to track selection range in iframe's designMode?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

I've been experimenting with this for a while but didn't get anything working well — is there any way to track mouseups and selections in iframe's designMode, preferably in a cross-browser compatible mode?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small snippet of code I found [here](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/wysiwyg-text-formating-t88886.html), hope it helps:

```
function setRange(rte) {
    //function to store range of current selection
    var oRTE;
    if (document.all) {
        oRTE = frames[rte];
        var selection = oRTE.document.selection;
        if (selection != null) rng = selection.createRange();
    } else {
        oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow;
        var selection = oRTE.getSelection();
        rng = selection.getRangeAt(selection.rangeCount - 1).cloneRange();
    }
    return rng;
}
```

Seems like you can use the `selection` attribute on the document object, and then use the `createRange()` method. The `if-else` is probably for cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great [Introduction to Range](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) from Quirksmode.  A great overview for getting text selections safely cross-browser.